# How to escape the other parameters which exists in between the preferred dynamic parameters in regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following expression:

"LASTNAME":"Jhonson","VIEWTYPE":"owner","ACCEPTSTATEID":4,"SUBSCRIBERCOUNT":1,"PROVIDERLASTUPDATE":"","MSG_NEW_FLAG":true,"PATIENTNAME":"Jhonson, Tim ","PATIENTGENDER":"M","FIRSTNAME":"Tim","ADMITTYPEID":7,"CASEOWNERCONTACTID":3102404757,

**Question-1**
I want to extract the first & last dynamic values i.e. "LASTNAME" & "CASEOWNERCONTACTID" using Regular Expression Extractor. 
How to escape the other parameters which exists in between these two.

**Question-2**
Also, can only the "LASTNAME" be extracted by escaping the particular "CASEOWNERCONTACTID" ? 
I mean, need the "LASTNAME" having other than this "CASEOWNERCONTACTID":3102404757

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a JSON response, You can use `JSON Path Extractor` which is very easy to use.

https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0
(scroll down to 'Parsing JSON')

If you would like to use `Regular Expression Extractor`,

```
Reference Name     : reg.lastname.id
Regular Expression : "LASTNAME":"(.*?)".*?"CASEOWNERCONTACTID":([0-9]+)
```

You will get,

```
reg.lastname.id_g1=Jhonson
reg.lastname.id_g2=3102404757
```

Comment: Can I achieve the "LASTNAME" by mentioning the particular "CASEOWNERCONTACTID". Acctually, I need to have the LASTNAMES which doesn't belongs to particular CASEOWNERCONTACTID. Can it be achieved using regular expression query itself?